# Density of primes among the prime powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the relative density of the prime numbers among the set of prime powers? In particular, let $\Pi(x)$ be the number of prime powers less than $x$ and let $\pi(x)$ be the number of primes less than $x$. What can be said of the limit

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{\Pi(x)}?$$

In other words, what is the density of prime powers which are square-free? My intuition says the answer should be $1$, but I'm not sure. -- in $\mathbb{Z}$, the square-free integers make up only $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$. On the other hand, in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$, the square-free polynomials of degree $n$ are $1 + o_n(1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument below is not elegant, but it works.

The number of perfect powers below $x$ is easily bounded by $ \sum_{n = 2}^{\log_2 x} \lfloor x^{1/n} \rfloor  \le  x^{1/2} \log x$.

On the other hand the number of primes  below $x$  is about $x/\log x$.

Bounding the number of prime powers (including primes) by the number of primes plus the number of perfect powers, the claim follows.

Comment: I think the OP is counting each prime $p$ as being a prime power, in which case the question is trickier. Perhaps the OP can comment?

Comment: I understood it that way. Otherwise the density would not be $1$ but inifnity. The point is that the number of  primepowers (including primes) are at most the number of  primes plus the number of perfect powers.

Comment: @TonyK This works -- the conclusion being that the density of primes among prime powers is $1$. Also, I think it's pretty elegant!

Comment: Yes, OK. But when you say "perfect powers", you mean "squares or higher powers", and when the OP says "prime powers", he means "primes or higher powers of primes". This confused me...

Comment: This answer is correct. More specifically $\pi(x)/\Pi(x) = 1-O(1/\sqrt x)$.

Comment: @TonyK I modified it slightly to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 3):

We can observe that if $p^{n}\leq x$ then $p\leq x^{1/n}$ so we can write $$\Pi\left(x\right)=\pi\left(x\right)+\pi\left(x^{1/2}\right)+\dots+\pi\left(x^{1/n}\right)
 $$ hence $$\Pi\left(x\right)=\pi\left(x\right)+O\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log\left(x\right)}\right).$$